# How to Automate Command Line taskkill without admin rights?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, automation

Tricky question but here's the thing.

I'm at work with a heinous security tool that blocks pretty much any ability to do anything.

I DO have permission to run /taskkill /F /IM someprocess.exe on the command line normally.

I want to do this daily because a certain software program --- only one person can access it at a time --- we work in different time zones. I usually close it every day manually, but there are misses. So I want to automate a task that kills it every night.

Here's the thing. ALL .bat files are blocked from running.

So my typical thought --- use Windows Task Scheduler to run a .bat file --- doesn't work.

So how else can I daily run this 'command line' command automatically? Is there no way? I do have access to do it manually of course (via command line directly). I can also do the regular end-task on windows task manager. I even have local admin rights of some sort (initially given so I stop pestering them with installs every week that require IT approval). But those can't seem to get around the .bat thing or 'highest privileges' in Windows Task Scheduler.

Another question --- I never log out of my computer, but the computer of course 'locks' nightly. The script would need to run while the computer is logged on to my account, but locked, nightly.

The easiest way is to go to IT, which I will do, but ... permissions every time I need to run a .bat file? There has to be a better way ... Also I'm not so sure if they will take a week to approve each time ...

Comment: Save the script as `.cmd` extension rather than `.bat`.

Comment: Schedule a command task instead of a script task!

Comment: Great idea -- really had fingers crossed --- .cmd tasks are also blocked :(

Comment: @user45867 Goto **`Task Scheduler` >`Create a Basic Task` > `Fill The Forms` > `Set  to Run Daily` > `Select your Preferred Time` > `Start a Program` > `Browse to C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` > `Add arguments: /C taskkill /F /IM someprocess.exe`**. Check and let me know if that works?

Comment: @protek, not sure how you came to the conclusion that a `.cmd` file would have made a difference in privilges above a `.bat` file?

Comment: Probably, @Gerhard,  they thought there was a chance the admin only restricted the running of `.bat` files by extension.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Because he said, he had access to `command line` so i thought perhaps they might have restrictions limited to only `.bat` files.

Comment: @compo.. i guess then the admin is from the 90s :D

Comment: Hmm it says the arguments are invalid. Whether I enter the arguments as specified or even just leave them blank. I know the filepath to cmd.exe is correct. Odd.

Comment: @user45867 Are you creating a **`new basic task`** or editing one? Editing will not work, i believe you will have add a **`new basic task`** for it to work.

Comment: Scratch my last comment --- even the simplest of tasks are not working properly in Task Scheduler --- so I believe despite the cryptic error message, it's probably more permissions BS unfortunately --- looks like I'll have to wait for IT to get this smoothed out ...

Comment: @user45867 Yeah, the admin sure knows his sh*t then. Well, i tried. Cheerio.

Answer (score 0):

```
taskkill /im process /f
```

Just schedule this command.

There is absolutely no need for CMD.exe or a bat file.

You can schedule for your own user account by ticking *run only when user logged in*.

To schedule

```
 SCHTASKS /Create /SC DAILY /it /TN taskkill /TR "Taskkill /f /im program.exe"
```